# How to change DataRange independently for various lists in same plot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting three lists of different size on the same plot. I want the plot to start from zero rather than 1 on the x-axis. In the past, I have used `DataRange->{0,Max}` to achieve this, but in this case the data range of all lists is changed, which is not what I want.

For example, consider:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
c = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

ListLogPlot[{a, b, c}, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

which yields:

[image]

If I add in the DataRange requirement,
`ListLogPlot[{a, b, c}, Joined -> True,  PlotMarkers -> {"a", "b", "c"}, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"},  DataRange -> {0, 7}]`,
I get the following plot, where all my lists are stretched to span the range 0->7:

[image]

I want each list to start at zero, but preserve its range (so 0->2 for a, 0-> 4 for b, etc. ). I am plotting them all together rather than creating different plots because I need the legend.

Comment: You could provide the x coordinate you want explicitly, like a->`Transpose[{Range[0, Length[a]-1], a}]` and so on.

Comment: That does the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) with time spec `Automatic` to get *uniformly spaced times starting at 0*:

```
td = TemporalData[{a, b, c}, Automatic];

ListLogPlot[td, Joined -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> (Style[#, 14, Background -> White] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"})]
```

[image]

Use [`TimeSeriesRescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesRescale.html) to modify time ranges:

```
ListLogPlot[TimeSeriesRescale[td, {10, 12}] , 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"},
 PlotMarkers -> (Style[#, 14, Background -> White] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
c = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
ListLogPlot[
 Table[MapIndexed[{First[#2] - 1, #1} &, x], {x, {a, b, c}}], 
 Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, 7}, PlotMarkers -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

[image]